# Birds of Prey (TV Show) - Messed up timeline?

Tags: dc

So I am in the middle of a Birds of Prey marathon. Watching all the episodes in order I am confused by the timeline. Am I missing something or did they just really mess up?

In the "Lady Shiva" episode, Helena has not seen Sandra in 8 years.

Then in the "Reunion" episode, it is their 5 year High School reunion.

In the "Lady Shiva" episode, Sandra tells a story about the beginning of Sophomore year...

So the only way I can work this is out is that Sandra disappeared just after the beginning of Sophomore Year? But I don't really think this makes sense, if Sandra is her "best friend from high school". That would also make Sandra 15 during the flashbacks with Barbra.

Is there a better way to resolve this timeline?

Comment: Helena has a lousy sense of the passage of time?